# Modules i18n: How to set the default language home page url without alias

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have a standard Drupal 7 installation with the i18n module and 3 languages defined.

- one basic page "node/1" created with the URL alias "home"
- in the Configuration > System > Site Information the default front page is "home"
- created other 2 languages (pt-br and it)
- created the translation of the basic page "node/1" to pt-br and it (are created "node/2" and "node/3" pages)
- the 3 pages "node/1, 2 and 3" have the same alias "home"

If I go to mysite/en, I see the defined front page in english and all the site is in english: it's ok!

The problems:

1. If I go to mysite/pt-br/home, I see the site in portuguese and the "node/1" in porguguese: it's ok!
2. If I go to mysite/pt-br, I see the site in portuguese but the "node/1" content in english and not the "node/2" (portuguese version of the basic page): wrong!
3. the same thing to the italian version.

What is wrong? How to set the correct language node for front page in the default language url (mysite/pt-br and mysite/it)?

Note: In the Detection and Selection tab is the original items with the default order (URL, Session, User, Browser and Default) and I have been enabled all (in the Configure page of URL the selected option is the Path Prefix).

Comment: What have you selected in admin/config/regional/language/configure?

Comment: In the Detection and Selection tab is the original items with the default order (URL, Session, User, Browser and Default) and I have been enabled all. (in the Configure page of URL the selected option is the Path Prefix)

Comment: Enabling all of them makes it really hard to figure which ones are effective. Try just the URL first (with default).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to declare your home page node as a "*multilingual varialable*". For more details on these kind of variables, and how to get this to work, refer to my answer at [How to make content translation available for front page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/158537/content-translation-for-front-page-is-not-available/158591#158591).

I'd be interested to some day hear if this  resolved the issue here.