# Why are foreign language registrants redirected to home page after registration?

Tags: 7, users, i18n-l10n, redirection

When someone registers an account in English (default language) the registrant is redirected to the Login page with a message: "A welcome message with further instructions has been sent to your e-mail address."

So far, so good.

But when a registrant select a foreign language on the registration page (like **es** for Spanish,) he is redirected to his profile page after submitting his registration.

Anyone knows how to fix this bug so that it behaves like the English registration? Or a workaround?

Comment: not sure I understand.  if the user sets his language preference to "es" he *should* end up at the spanish home page... because that's what his language is set as.

Comment: When they create an account, new members cannot just enter their profile page as there is an email verification process. So they need to click on the link inside the email that is sent to them to enter their profile page. That's how it works in English. But for Spanish, the email verification process is bypassed and the new registrant is taken directly to his profile page.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if your issue could be related to the language specific homepage (frontpage).

The relative URL to display as the front page is specified within admin/config/system/site-information. Make sure you specify a value for it that is different for each of the site's languages. To do so, you have to make it a "multilingual" variable (it should say "This is a multilingual variable.") in the description of that variable on that page.

For more details about this, refer to my answer at [How to make content translation available for front page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/158537/content-translation-front-page-not-avaible/158591#158591)

Comment: I have to study this. This is the first time I hear of those variables. The rest of the site works well in Spanish. Each page has a drop-down that allows the user to select the language. Upon selection of a different language, the page is refreshed and reappears in the new language so I never had to bother with variable translation. I did, however, follow your tutorial for the front page and indeed I see the selector at the top of the administration page. For the front page, the variable is set at <front> for all languages. Should it be different?

Comment: Here again, we are talking about the new account registration page. After registering using a foreign language, the user is redirected to his profile page. I don't see how the front page is relevant to the registration page or profile page. But again, I need to study this thoroughly.

Comment: As a fix I was thinking either a redirect rule or a small module. I have more than 500 modules on this site so I need to keep it and the database lean and mean. If there is a bug, then it should be fixed.