# Multilingual multisite problem after changing standard language

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n, multi-sites

We have a multisite and one site is multilingual with (i18n). It contains a lot of translated views (title and standard words like "more" being translated with Views translation (i18nviews)). This works very well as long as the standard language (atm german) is not changed. If we change to another language as standard the view translations are not working anymore, which means the new language gets mixed up with the old standard language on that specific view items.

Has someone else run into this? Where is the configuration setting to get this solved?

Thanks in advance.

Background for this is, that the client wanted another language as front page (so if there's a hint how to solve this in a multisite environment other than changing the standard language, be welcome. We have tried a bunch of htaccess redirects to no avail).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a *hint* (as in your question), that might help: make sure the URL of the homepage is defined as a "multilingual" variable. The relative URL to display as the front page is specified within `admin/config/system/site-information`.

If you want to be able to specify a value for it that is different for each of the site's languages, make sure you have made it a "multilingual" variable (it should say "**`This is a multilingual variable.`**" in the description of that variable on that page).

For more details about how to get this done, refer to my answer to "[How to make content translation available for front page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/158537/content-translation-front-page-not-avaible/158591#158591)".

Answer (score 0):

Try this module https://www.drupal.org/project/lingotek, everything you need is solved with this module, it translate variables, nodes, labels, views, everything. They have a youtube channel https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-ePFjCRHGIPtDzJDb459Yg

Comment: This is not an answer to the question "use module X" as that won't solve the problem at hand.

Comment: Hi clemmens, it may not be an answer to you, but it is, it, solves the problem in question, i have built several multilingual sites with the module i mention, i had several translation problems like this one, and guess what, the module solves it, i'm pointing the solution to a new direction, and yes, it solves what the question is about. i totally desagree with your downvote, you only are pushing members to NOT help others.

Comment: Thanks for this, pineuve. The module looks promising, but i haven't had the time to check this out. I was hoping for a quickfix to my question, but quick and multilanguage is quite incommensurate... :o)

Comment: Thanks Volker for accepting my answer, feel free to ask me any thing about module implementation. Have a nice Friday. Regards.